# Finding the dimension of kernel and Image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathcal{P}_2[x] \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_3[x]$ linear transformation defined by:

$T(p(x)) = 3p'(x) + p''(x) + \int_{2}^{x+1}p(t-2)dt$

Find $dim(Im T) $ and $ dim( Ker T)$

My approach is to find the $Im(T)$ by plugging in the standard basis of the starting set $\mathcal{P}_2[x]$ : $\mathcal{B} = \{1,x,x^2\}$ into the transformation to obtain the elements that will span $Im(T)$.

My only obstacle is the shifting in the integral that is confusing me a bit. I know that for $T(1)$ the first two terms dissapear but how do I take the integral? Is $p(t-2)$ just $1$? Is it $-1$?

What happens with $T(x)$ in the integral?

Comment: If $p(x)=1$ then $p(t-2)=1$ too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now for $p(x) = x$ would $p(t-2) = t-2?$?

Comment: Yes it's just substitution as usual.

Comment: One last question: the upper bound of the integral will remain $x+2$ for all cases, right? It shouldn't depend on the input of $T(p(x))$, right?

Comment: Yes. You're integrating with respect to $t$ so the bound only applies when you evaluate the integral at the end.

Comment: Thanks, got the problem!